# Semantical Error The annotation \"@Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Constraints\\NotBlank\" in property was never imported

Tags: php, slim, symfony, doctrine-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma simples API com Microframework Slim utilizando o Doctrine, decidi implementar algumas validações, então instalei a biblioteca `symfony/validator:^5.2`.

Nas minhas entidades, tenho algumas annotations do doctrine, e resolvi adicionar algumas do symfony, então fiz a importação 
`use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;`
  em seguida nos atributos da da class, adicionei a annotation

`* @Constraints\NotBlank()`

Porém recebo a seguinte Exception: `[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property App\Entity\UserType::$description was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?`

Segue imagem de como foi implementado: 
[image: Código da entidade, arquivo composer.json e exception no postman]

**Informações adicionais**

- PHP: 8
- Já desinstalei a biblioteca e instalei novamente: Obs: **o erro continua mesmo depois de remover a lib `symfony/validator` como se o erro fosse de outra lib ex: doctrine.;**
- O doctrine está lendo as annotations corretamente e gerando as tabelas do banco de dados
- Já dei o composer dump-autoload

Comment: Tenta chamar o 'NotBlank' sem ser uma função (remove as () da anotação). Também, de acordo com a documentação do symfony (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html#basic-usage), tenta alterar seu import usando um alias e veja se faz alguma diferença.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão Renan!  Acabei de fazer isso, fiz a importação colocando um alias:  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; e chamei da seguinte forma no atributo: * @Assert\NotBlank    Porém sem sucesso ainda!

Comment: Nesse caso, tenta importar a classe NotBlank diretamente: `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;`

Comment: Importei ela também, dessa forma e a exception continuou,  um colega me deu a sugestão de fazer isso AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([require __DIR__ .'/../../vendor/autoload.php', 'loadClass']);
 Aparentemente resolveu a exception porém, não esta validando, está inserindo o campo vazio mesmo no bd, não sei se tenho que fazer algo mais, alguma sugestão ?

Comment: O autoload.php deve ser chamado no ponto de entrada da sua aplicação, nesse caso, imagino que deva haver um index.php dentro do seu diretório public. Veja se dentro do index você está chamando esse autoload. Sugiro dar uma olhada no repo do Slim (https://github.com/slimphp/Slim), tem uma implementação do index.php lá que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Certo obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.